# Using uploaded file to create choropleth map gives error: "'by' must specify a uniquely valid column"

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm trying to allow the user to upload a CSV file, and with that CSV file, ggplot2 generates a choropleth using the mean plastics of each New Jersey county.

I believe I did the file input correctly, because the table that I wanted to generate next to the map did generate. The map didn't generate though. Here's what the app looks like after the user uploads their data:

[image: The table generates, but the map doesn't.]

To reproduce this, you'll need to download the New Jersey counties geojson file:

[download link for NJ county boundaries geojson](https://njogis-newjersey.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/newjersey::county-boundaries-of-nj/explore?location=40.122071%2C-74.743150%2C8.67)

And you'll also need the CSV of the data, which can be copied and pasted from here into Excel or Google Sheets and exported as a CSV (if there's an easier way for me to do this, please let me know):

| COUNTY | PLASTICS | PAPERS | METALS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ATLANTIC | 340 | 260 | 45 |
| ATLANTIC | 300 | 210 | 35 |
| BERGEN | 325 | 453 | 123 |
| BURLINGTON | 467 | 223 | 124 |
| BURLINGTON | 545 | 235 | 224 |
| ESSEX | 354 | 356 | 124 |
| MIDDLESEX | 433 | 324 | 134 |
| CAPE MAY | 325 | 274 | 342 |
| CAPE MAY | 324 | 540 | 230 |
| CAPE MAY | 653 | 346 | 243 |
| MONMOUTH | 768 | 475 | 324 |
| MONMOUTH | 457 | 462 | 125 |
| MONMOUTH | 486 | 342 | 323 |
| MONMOUTH | 944 | 354 | 122 |
| MONMOUTH | 356 | 435 | 334 |
| MONMOUTH | 457 | 346 | 421 |
| OCEAN | 568 | 234 | 401 |

Here is the reproducible code:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(geojsonio)
library(sp)
library(sf)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    h1(strong("NJ Beachsweep Mapping with R"), align = "center"),
    column(
      6,
      plotOutput('plot')
    ),
    column(
      6,
      h4(strong('Upload CSV file to begin')),
      fileInput('uploaded_data', NULL, accept = '.csv'),
      tableOutput("contents")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  input_file <- reactive({
    file <- input$uploaded_data
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    req(file)
    counties_and_trash <- read_csv(file$datapath)
    mean_each_type <- counties_and_trash %>%
      group_by(COUNTY) %>%
      summarise(
        mean_plastics = mean(PLASTICS, na.rm = TRUE),
        mean_papers = mean(PAPERS, na.rm = TRUE),
        mean_metals = mean(METALS, na.rm = TRUE)
      ) |>
      mutate(COUNTY = toupper(COUNTY))
  })
  
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    input_file()
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(input_file)
    
    spdf <- geojson_read("County_Boundaries_of_NJ.geojson", what = "sp")
    # Convert to sf
    spdf <- sf::st_as_sf(spdf)
    
    merged <- merge(spdf, mean_each_type, by = 'COUNTY')
    ggplot(merged) +
      # Use geom_sf
      geom_sf(aes(fill = mean_plastics)) +
      theme_void()
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The issue is with the `merge` function - is the join column titled and spelled exactly the same way (same capitalization) in both data frames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce your issue and the error you get. I can only guess that there was already an object named `mean_each_type` in your global environment because otherwise you would get a error that there is no object `mean_each_type` (as I did).

But the main issue with your code is that you are not using the uploaded file in `merge`.

To do so you have to use `merge(spdf, input_file(), by = 'COUNTY')` instead of `merge(spdf, mean_each_type, by = 'COUNTY')` (The latter will give the mentioned error in a clean R session). Additionally I added a `req()` to check that the a file has been uploaded (Otherwise we get an error too). And finally I moved the import of the shapefile outside of `renderPlot`, i.e. as long as the shape file does not change it's fine to import it just once per session not each time the `renderPlot` is called.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(geojsonio)
library(sp)
library(sf)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    h1(strong("NJ Beachsweep Mapping with R"), align = "center"),
    column(
      6,
      plotOutput('plot')
    ),
    column(
      6,
      h4(strong('Upload CSV file to begin')),
      fileInput('uploaded_data', NULL, accept = '.csv'),
      tableOutput("contents")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  spdf <- geojson_read("County_Boundaries_of_NJ.geojson", what = "sp")
  # Convert to sf
  spdf <- sf::st_as_sf(spdf)

  input_file <- reactive({
    file <- input$uploaded_data
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    req(file)
    counties_and_trash <- read_csv(file$datapath)
    mean_each_type <- counties_and_trash %>%
      group_by(COUNTY) %>%
      summarise(
        mean_plastics = mean(PLASTICS, na.rm = TRUE),
        mean_papers = mean(PAPERS, na.rm = TRUE),
        mean_metals = mean(METALS, na.rm = TRUE)
      ) |>
      mutate(COUNTY = toupper(COUNTY))
  })
  
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    input_file()
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(input_file())
  
    merged <- merge(spdf, input_file(), by = 'COUNTY')
    ggplot(merged) +
      # Use geom_sf
      geom_sf(aes(fill = mean_plastics)) +
      theme_void()
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't realize that input_file needed to be used in merge instead of mean_each_type. You've been extremely helpful!